# CSS Parallax overflow-y:scroll make it disaper

Tags: html, css, parallax

i have succeded in making **pure css** parallax, it was hard ! ^^

But I got a problem.

To do the parallax we have to ad `overflow-y : scroll` propriety in order to scroll the block with perspective propriety from up to down.

The thing is that it force me to ad a ugly scroll bar, how could I remove it ?

Thanks ! :)

Here is my snippet:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.parent{
    perspective: 200px;
    perspective-origin: bottom right;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.parent:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(white, #A00000);
    height: 300vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

section{
    height: 50vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

span{
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/248/248983.png') no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.firstChild{
    transform: translateZ(-200px);
}

.secondChild{
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/248/248983.png') no-repeat;
    transform: translateZ(-100px) ;
}

.secondChild{
    transform: translateZ(-300px) ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> My website is not awesome.</h1>
    <div class="parent">
        
        <section><span class="firstChild"></span></section>
        <section><span class="secondChild"></span></section>
        <section><span class="thirdChild"></span></section>
        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css to make the scrollbar invisible:

```css
.parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```